# create arcsde service, "The ArcSDE administrator user (sde) must have DBADM authority to install or upgrade ArcSDE for DB2."

Tags: db2, installation, privileges

arcsde10 is installed in windows7 pc as a pcA, db2 9.5 is installed in windows server 2003 pc as pcb. in pcb,there is a "sde" user in "db2admin","db2user" and "administrator" group. in pcA, execute `sdesetup -o prerequisite_check -d db2 -d gisdb13  -u sde` by arcsde command line, then input the password, show message "Checking INSTALL privileges for geodatabase ...
Current user does not have privilege to install geodatabase instance.
The ArcSDE administrator user (sde) must have DBADM authority to install or upgrade ArcSDE for DB2."

Why does the user "sde" not have DBADM authority? The "sde" is in "db2admin" group.
 sorry, my english is not good, thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

Db2admin is usually SYSADM group, not DBADM of the database. That shouldn't matter, but I guess ArcSDE installation checks specifically for DBADM grant. It's a bug, you should report it to ESRI. What you can do is just

```
grant dbadm to sde
```

and that should resolve the issue.